# (Node.js) How to change a global variable inside a mongoDB function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

Here there is an example code:

```
//IF I JUST TRY TO CONNECT TO MONGODB
function ConnectToMongo(db) {
    myVar = false;
    db.collection("MyCollection", function(error,collection) { 
        myVar = true;
    });
    console.log(myVar); // RETURN TRUE
}

//IF I TRY TO INSERT DATA
function InsertDataOnMongoDB(db) {
    myVar = false;
    db.collection("MyCollection", function(error,collection) { 
        collection.insert(data, function(error,result){
            myVar = true;
        });
    });
    return myVar; // RETURNS FALSE!!
}
```

How can I execute the last line line "return myVar" only after collection.insert function ends? I need to return true, in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It displays `false` because these two functions before `console.log` are asynchronous. For this reason `console.log` is executed while `db.collection` and `collection.insert` are still executing, so `myVar = true;` starts when these two operations have finished.

In order to see "true" you have to insert your `console.log` straight after `myVar = true;`

This way:

```
db.collection("MyCollection", function(error, collection){
    collection.insert(data, function(error, result){
        myVar = true;
        console.log(myVar);
    });
});
```

Comment: You were faster than me haha!

Comment: Haha! It was easy :P